# rosrun xacro xacro.py nao_robot_v4_structure.urdf.xacro fails

Tags: ros, collada-urdf, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The other day, I send following question to University of Freiburg who made this package, and got an answer.
I hope you can benefit from this as well if you have the same problem.

I'm also using NAO robot too
(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KfqmXQtRGo), and try to use
nao_description package, but I have following error. If you know how
to fix this, please let me know.

```
tsuji@leda:~/ros/electric/alufr-ros-pkg/nao_common/nao_description/urdf$
rosrun xacro xacro.py nao_robot_v4_structure.urdf.xacro  >
nao_structure.urdf

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/xacro.py", line 35, in <module>
   xacro.main()
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 558, in main
   eval_self_contained(doc)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 499, in
eval_self_contained
   eval_all(doc.documentElement, macros, symbols)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 483, in eval_all
   result = eval_text(at[1], symbols)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 402, in eval_text
   results.append(handle_expr(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 390, in handle_expr
   return eval_expr(lex, symbols)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 364, in eval_expr
   result = eval_term(lex, symbols)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 339, in eval_term
   result = eval_factor(lex, symbols)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 320, in eval_factor
   return neg * eval_lit(lex, symbols)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 298, in eval_lit
   raise XacroException("Property wasn't defined: %s" % str(ex))
xacro.XacroException: Property wasn't defined: u'pi_2'
```

And I got following answer.

```
The file is not meant to be used stand-alone because it includes only the structure without visualization. You need to run "rosrun xacro xacro.py nao_robot_v4.urdf.xacro"

Or directly start the state_publisher as well with the launch file with launch/nao_v4_publisher.launch.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33700/rosrun-xacro-xacro.py-nao_robot_v4_structure.urdf.xacro-fails/) by [JunpeiTsuji](https://answers.ros.org/users/2357/junpeitsuji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably this is a late answer, but it can be useful for someone else.

I had a similar problem with other package, apparently the reason is that property tags cannot be declared inside of a xacro:macro. And unfortunately, for nao_description package some macros in "visuals.xacro" use "pi" and "pi_2" properties, so when it copies theirs contents in "nao_robot_v4_structure.urdf.xacro" file, this two properties don't appear.
One solution is move this two properties:

< xacro:property name="pi" value="3.1415926535897931"/>

< xacro:property name="pi_2" value="1.5707963267948966"/>

to "nao_robot_v4_structure.urdf.xacro" file.

---

Originally posted by [domingoesteban](https://answers.ros.org/users/4759/domingoesteban/) with karma: 16 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-02-28**:
The best way to request fixes or improvements would be to submit an issue to the corresponding GitHub repo. You can even contribute fixes via fork / pull request.